# Obtain array of puppet virtual resources

Tags: puppet

Is there a way to obtain a list of virtual resources in puppet?

I have my users setup as virtual resources:

```
@accounts::user_virtual { 'dscott':
  uid => 600,
  ssh_key => 'AAAAAAAAAA...',
}

... other users here
```

And I have a hiera value which contains the list of users enabled:

```
'dscott,user1,user2,...'
```

So, on each node, I want to add the user who are in the list, and make sure that users who have been removed from the list are removed from the server. So, I need to 'subtract' the list of all users from the list in my hiera value.

How can I obtain a list of 'all users'? Ideally I'd like to get a list of all `accounts::user_virtual` resources.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set `ensure => absent` for the user, not remove the resource definition.

The reason is that if a host is not checking into Puppet you want to ensure the account will be removed when it eventually does. So, leave the resource definition, change the state.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i want to do. So, i need a list of 'all users' so that i can loop through the full list and either add users of they're in my list and remove them if they're not